# Can we store any dynamic date or time in Figma's variable?

Tags: layers, style, figma, data-visualisation

I have been using Figma for my design since past 3 years now that that have there new update where we can add static number data in their variables.

[image]

I want to store a `dynamic date` in it instead of a hard-coded number.
Is there any plugin or any way to do it?